# Is there solution for localhost error 404?

Tags: javascript, localhost, npm-install, local, npm-scripts

I tried to access my file on [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost), but it shows an error like below:

```
Not Found
404
NotFoundError: Not Found
    at C:\Users\RMUSER1\Desktop\Rainbowmedia\test1\billing-bakery\app.js:50:8
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\RMUSER1\Desktop\Rainbowmedia\test1\billing-bakery\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\RMUSER1\Desktop\Rainbowmedia\test1\billing-bakery\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\Users\RMUSER1\Desktop\Rainbowmedia\test1\billing-bakery\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\RMUSER1\Desktop\Rainbowmedia\test1\billing-bakery\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\RMUSER1\Desktop\Rainbowmedia\test1\billing-bakery\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at C:\Users\RMUSER1\Desktop\Rainbowmedia\test1\billing-bakery\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:15
    at next (C:\Users\RMUSER1\Desktop\Rainbowmedia\test1\billing-bakery\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:260:14)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\RMUSER1\Desktop\Rainbowmedia\test1\billing-bakery\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (C:\Users\RMUSER1\Desktop\Rainbowmedia\test1\billing-bakery\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take your time. Start by taking a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). In particular, pay attention to advices on asking questions. Currently your question lacks details, contains no code and possibly will be closed because of insufficient information.

Comment: Access the file in what context? Contrary to [popular belief](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186035/policy-and-rationale-for-making-close-votes-invisible-to-most-users/186047#186047), we are not mind-readers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open another browser and restart your code. And also connect to the Internet.

Comment: Yes tried and same error shown